# Intermittent failure of showinfo=0 in YouTube iframe embed

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

The YouTube embeds on our site have been unpredictable for a few months regarding the `showinfo` parameter.

When you load a webpage containing any YouTube embed(s), you never know if the `showinfo=0` parameter will function on any given iframe. Often, you see the title and channel branding anyway.

Refreshing the page generally makes `showinfo=0` work as intended for every iframe on that page.

Does YouTube (or anyone) know why this issue might be happening, or anything we can do to solve it?

Comment: I've been thinking this might relate to some kind of asynchronicity -- i.e., the videos load but the settings don't necessarily manage to load at the right time to affect those embeds.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar issue it seems as though some folks are in a youtube A/B test and the `showinfo=0` does not work for those users. Here is the titlebar visible even though `showinfo=0`.

**Youtube iframe embed with showinfo=0**
[image: Youtube iframe embed with showinfo=0]

**User watching an embed with existing title bar not in A/B test?**
[image: User watching an embed with existing title bar not in A/B test?]

**User watching an embed in new Title A/B test**
[image: User watching an embed in new Title A/B test]

Comment: Our issue has not been user dependent. It can affect different videos on the same page differently at the same time for the same user.